# « Comme tous les châteaux du Moyen Âge » où tous est prononcé \tut\ se compare-t-il à la prononciation d'une finale muette au Québec ?

Tags: orthographe, oral, québec, registre

Dans une [séquence](https://youtu.be/89CAY3gTWCo) de film on entend un enfant dire :

> Le château fort qu'on va faire, là, les murs vont être large « comme
> ça »,
>  Il va être plus gros que ma maison, plus haut que les
> arbres,
>  Il va, il va être super impressionnant, il va n'en avoir juste
> « un » château fort comme ça,
>  Avec des tours, des créneaux, plein de
> décorations, des portes, des fenêtres,
>  Toutes des affaires secrètes,
> on va même pouvoir y manger dedans,
>  Il va avoir tout qu'est-ce
> qu'on pourra mettre,
>  Il va être vraiment super beau, comme **tous**
> les châteaux du Moyen Âge,
>  Super super beau.
>
> [ François « Les Lunettes » ds. la [*Guerre des tuques*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Guerre_des_tuques) (Mélançon,
> 1984) ]

Ce *tous* est prononcé comme *toute* (\tut\ ). Il est [possible](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Consonnes) qu'à l'oral, en français québécois populaire ou familier, on prononce des finales muettes en *t* (comme *tout*). Comme la nature et la fonction de [*tout*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2910) peut varier et le mot connaît bien des emplois, on a évidemment différentes manières de le prononcer selon l'accord (genre, nombre) ou non.

- En français québécois pense-t-on que la prononciation dans la
  séquence est négativement marquée ou d'un registre ou sociolecte
  différent comparativement à la prononciation d'une finale normalement
  muette en *t* parce que la prononciation n'est pas appuyée par
  l'orthographe requise (*tous*) ?
- Quand on retranscrit de telles paroles, comme plus haut, comment
  peut-on noter cette particularité à l'écrit (symboles, API, doublet
  avec ponctuation) ; est-ce justifiable ?

Answer (score 2):

Disons d'abord qu'en français québécois traditionnel (c'est à dire sans influence aucune de la norme cultivée), la règle est assez simple: *tout* est invariable, aussi bien dans ses emplois adjectivaux qu'adverbiaux, avec la prononciation [tʊt]. Il y a un petit nombre d'exceptions (par exemple, *tous les* [twe], *tout simplement* [tu]).

C'est un peu plus compliqué que ça en réalité, parce que *tout* s'emploie comme adverbe dans des cas qu'on ne verrait pas en France, comme dans

- *J'ai tout* [tʊt] *mangé le pain.*

Parfois on évite des emplois pronominaux de *tout*. Par exemple, on évite *Tout/Tous sont venus* à la faveur de *Ils sont tout* [tʊt] *venus*.

La variation qu'on observe provient principalement de la concurrence entre le québécois traditionnel et la norme. En particulier, on rencontre parfois des cas d'hypercorrection, c'est-à-dire des [tu] là où la norme serait [tʊt]:

- *J'ai rangé tout(es)* [tu] *les tasses.*

Pour moi, il est indéniable que le *tout* invariable est marqué socialement. Ceci dit, il est vrai aussi qu'il y a des gens qui parlent en général un français correct, je dirais une minorité, qui sont à l'aise pour employer cette forme dans des situations sociales où on s'attendrait au registre neutre. Donc je pense que c'est un point sur lequel les jugements d'acceptabilité divergent. Dans les situations familières, il me semble que la plupart des gens font usage du *tout* invariable.

Pour répondre à la question concernant la notation, dans un texte où on veut attirer l'attention sur une prononciation non-standard de *tout*, on rencontrera souvent les graphies *toute* ou *toutes*. Grammaticalement, on a affaire à une forme de *tout* qui n'est pas féminine, donc cette pratique sert uniquement à souligner la prononciation.

Par contre, dans un cadre scientifique on peut bien sûr utiliser l'API.